# frame width return slarge number

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a slider whose width and height is 200 x 10

```
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 200.0, 10.0);

UISlider *slider = [[UISlider alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

When I log

```
NSLog(@"WIDTH: %d", slider.frame.size.width);
```

I get back

```
WIDTH: 396044417
```

which is a large number and seems incorrect. Is this normal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%d` is for printing integers, for floating point values you have to use `%f`. You can also limit the number of decimal digits using `%.2f`.

The best solution though is logging the whole frame:

```
NSLog(@"Frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(slider.frame));
```

Comment: oh yeah..just made the realization for my mistake haha thanks

Comment: @poopit You probably had a compiler warning :)

Comment: The warning probably also offered to fix the error (click on the yellow warning triangle), don't ignore warnings, they are your friend.